# Standard deviation/error of linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

So I have:

```
t = [0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.2, 10.0, 13.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0, 35.0]
U = [12.5, 10.0, 7.6, 6.0, 4.4, 3.1, 2.5, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.3]
U_0 = 12.5
y = []
for number in U:
    y.append(math.log(number/U_0, math.e))
(m, b) = np.polyfit(t, y, 1)
yp = np.polyval([m, b], t)
plt.plot(t, yp)
plt.show()
```

So by doing this I get linear regression fit with `m=-0.1071` and `b=0.0347`.

How do I get deviation or error for m value?

I would like `m = -0.1071*(1+ plus/minus error)`

> m is k and b is n in y=kx+n

Comment: [How to find error on slope and intercept using numpy.polyfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634270/how-to-find-error-on-slope-and-intercept-using-numpy-polyfit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import math

U = [12.5, 10.0, 7.6, 6.0, 4.4, 3.1, 2.5, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.3]
U_0 = 12.5
y = []

for number in U:
    y.append(math.log(number/U_0, math.e))

y = np.array(y)

t = np.array([0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.2, 10.0, 13.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0, 35.0])
t = sm.add_constant(t, prepend=False)

model = sm.OLS(y,t)
result = model.fit()
result.summary()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `scipy.stats.linregress` :

```
m, b, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(t, yp)
```

The quality of the linear regression is given by the correlation coefficient in `r_value`, being `r_value = 1.0` for a perfect correlation.

Note that, `std_err` is the standard error of the estimated gradient, and not from the linear regression.