# Error of slope using numpy.polyfit and dependent variable

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, standard-deviation

I am having trouble understanding the error estimates between the variables when performing linear regression. Referring to [How to find error on slope and intercept using numpy.polyfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634270/how-to-find-error-on-slope-and-intercept-using-numpy-polyfit/56643541#56643541) say I am fitting a straight line with `numpy.polyfit` (code below).

As mentioned in the question in the link, the square root of the diagonals of the covariance matrix are the estimated standard-deviation for each of the fitted coefficients, and so `np.sqrt(V[0][0]))` is the standard deviation of the slope. My question(s) is(are): how the standard deviation of `y` should be represented? Should it be the addition of the uncertainties *in quadrature*, i.e., y +/- `np.sqrt(np.sqrt(V[0][0])**2+np.sqrt(V[1][1])**2)` ? Or perhaps I could only represent it by the standard deviation of the residuals (which would be `np.sqrt(S)/(len(y)-1)`)? Finally, is it possible to obtain the residuals from the covariance matrix?

PS: thanks for the heads-up on adding an "answer" to a question.

```
import numpy as np

# Data for testing
x = np.array([0.24580423, 0.59642861, 0.35879163, 0.37891011, 0.02445137,
       0.23830957, 0.38793433, 0.68054104, 0.83934083, 0.76073689])

y = np.array([0.61502838, 1.01772738, 1.35351035, 1.32799754, 0.23326104,
       0.89275698, 0.689498  , 1.48300835, 2.324673  , 1.52208752])

p, V = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, cov=True)

p2, S, *rest = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, full=True)
```